# CXX Cmake Compiler is unknown

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, cmake

```
 ./cmake-3.4.1/bin/cmake ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    /usr/bin/c++

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

says it's invalid, but

```
/usr/bin/c++ is a valid path
```

Why is this error showing?

I tried running

```
/cmake-3.4.1/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/c++
```

and still got this error

EDIT

```
xmr-stak/build# ./cmake-3.4.1/bin/cmake ../ -DCMAKE_CXX+COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    /usr/bin/c++

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/monero/xmr-stak/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/root/monero/xmr-stak/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

from the cmake log:

```
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: /usr/bin/c++
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: /usr/bin/c++
Build flags:
Id flags: -c

The output was:
No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very strong suspicion that you have a mispelling (note the `g` in `g++`):

```
cmake ../ -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++
```

If you do indeed have your compiler executable named `c++`, then ensure that the following works:

```
$ /usr/bin/c++ --version
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I tried again, posted the command + typed plus output. I looked at the log file and it shows missing .. I tried `/usr/bin/c++(and g++) --version` and they are both missing. I'm thinking I will try a fresh install.. of the whole system